# WordPress Shortcode based on other shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have 2 WordPress shortcodes I am working on:

1. A Chapter. [chapter name="the begining"]...content...[/chapter]
2. A table of contents [toc][/toc]. The toc needs to display a simple list of the chapters.

Specification:

- There can be many chapters in a post.
- There can be one, two or no toc shortcode in a post.
- The toc can be either before or after the chapters or both before and after. It is up to the post writer so I don't know in advance.
- I cannot use nested shortcodes as those are difficult for writers to work with.

I thought of using  a static toc array to add chapters at each chapter tag and then output it in the toc shortcode. Alas, the toc shortcode can appear BEFORE the chapters and then the array will be empty.

The following post html will not show the toc:

```
[toc][/toc]
Here is some content
[chapter name="hello"]xxx[/chapter]
In between content may come here
[chapter name="world"]yyy[/chapter]
Some more stuff
```

This is my starting code (embeded in a class):

```
public static function register_chapter_shortcode($atts, $content=null){
    $atts = shortcode_atts (
        array (
            'name'       => '',
        ), $atts );

    $name = $atts["name"];
    if (self::$toc == null){
        self::$toc = array ($name);
    } else {
        array_push(self::$toc, $name);
    }
    return '
        <h2>'.$atts["name"].'</h2>
        <div>'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>'
    ;
}

public static function register_toc_shortcode($atts, $content=null){
    $items = "";
    foreach (self::$toc as $item){
        $items = $items. '<li><a href="#">'.$item.'</a></li>';
    }
    return '
        <ul>'.$items.'</ul>            
    ';
}
```

Comment: What output do you intent to display from `register_chapter_shortcode`?

Comment: it's not really important. You can assume: return do_shortcode($content);

Comment: So you do intend to output something? If you didn't you could just move `[toc]` to the end. `register_toc_shortcode` is running before `register_chapter_shortcode` has set up `self::$toc`, so it has nothing to display. The problem is the order the functions run, so you have to move `[toc]` to the end either way. If you need to display something in `[chapter]`, the only way I see to do this is either (1)  save *all* content to `self::$toc` in `register_chapter_shortcode` and output everything in `register_toc_shortcode` after the `[chapter]`s or (2) use jQuery to insert the toc into the DOM

Comment: Yes. I am outputting stuff. The chapter name and some more. TOC can be at top or bottom (and I heard some users want it twice). That's what makes it complicated: users. lol

Comment: You should make sure you have *all* your requirements in your question from the start. The inclusion of text between the shortcodes requires a totally different approach. I wasted quite a lot of time on preparing my answer below to meet your initial requirements, and I don't have more time to spare to help you now. Hopefully someone else will. I also think you are trying to achieve too much through shortcodes, they are not intended for anything that complex - you're trying to use them to process the content from the editor. Is there no other approach you could use, e.g. custom fields?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, these are the requirements of my users and hence my question. Custom fields are not possible.

Comment: What is the text between the [chapter] shortcodes? Could it be included inside the shortcodes, or be wrapped with a different shortcode?If I've time later or tomorrow I'll have a think about it but I really don't see how you can achieve everything you need with just those 2 shortcodes. Sometimes users just have to be given a reality check that some things just aren't viable :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order that the functions are running in: `register_toc_shortcode` is running before `register_chapter_shortcode` has set up `self::$toc`, so it has nothing to display. This means that `[toc]` has to come after the `[chapter]` shortcodes. The problem with this is that you need to display the TOC before the chapters are listed.

As I mentioned in my comment I can see 2 ways around this - one is to use javascript to insert the TOC into the DOM, but I'd avoid that if possible.

The other way is use `register_chapter_shortcode` to store *everything* in `self::$toc`, and output nothing itself. Then `register_toc_shortcode` can display all content.

This isn't tested, but the basic logic behind it should be correct:

```
public static function register_chapter_shortcode($atts, $content=null){
    $atts = shortcode_atts (
        array (
            'name'       => '',
        ), $atts );

    if (self::$toc == null)
        self::$toc = array ();

    /* add ALL info to self::$toc in an array */
    array_push(self::$toc, array("name" => $atts["name"], "content" => $content));
}

public static function register_toc_shortcode($atts, $content=null){
    /* add the ability to pass in the position of the toc, as required in your comment */
    $atts = shortcode_atts (
        array (
            'position' => 'top', /* e.g. "top" (default), "bottom", "both" */
        ), $atts );

    /* generate the HTML for the TOC */
    $toc_html = "<ul>";
    foreach (self::$toc as $item){
        $toc_html .= '<li><a href="#">'.$item["name"].'</a></li>';
    }
    $toc_html .= "</ul>";

    /* generate the HTML for the chapters */
    $chapters = "";
    foreach (self::$toc as $item){
        $chapters .= '<h2>'.$item["name"].'</h2>
        <div>'.do_shortcode($item["content").'</div>';
    }

    /* generate the output, putting the TOC at the top or bottom as required */
    $html = "";
    if ($position == "top" || $position == "both") $html .= $toc_html;
    $html .= $chapters;
    if ($position == "bottom" || $position == "both") $html .= $toc_html;

    return $html;
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
[chapter name="hello"]xxx[/chapter]
[chapter name="world"]yyy[/chapter]
[toc position="top"][/toc]
```

Note: `[toc]` *always* has to go after the `chapter`s so that they are set up for `[toc]` to display the details.

Comment: Thanks. But: 1. Users might want the TOC before or might it after or both. 2. This assumes that there is no other content on the post other than the shortcodes (never the case).

Comment: @checklist 1. No, my code allows for the TOC to be added at the top, bottom or both places, depending on the position specified in the shortcode - did you check the code in `register_toc_shortcode`? 2. I can only work with the information you included in your question - thats why I specifically asked in my comment! I've no idea what else you want to do if you don't tell us. If you have other  content, you can easily include that in the array in `register_chapter_shortcode`.